# How to filter from list view items containing image and text in custom adapter by entering text in edittext view

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

My motive is to filter and show items entered by user in edit textview from the list view items containing image and textview.But I am not able to filter properly (implementation is not correct i guess + newbie to Android)

I want to filter it by textview which is attached in adapter.I am able to  list items properly in list view (image + text). Only thing I want is in the edit text, if I enter any words, it should filter the list view items.
I have searched for the same and tried,but not successful.
For now I am referring this tutorial:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

1. Displaylist.java

   ```
   YouTubeAdapter you;
   ArrayList<String> VideoURL=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> VideoID=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> VideoTitle=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> VideoThumb=new ArrayList<String>();
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list_view);
   lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
   you=new YouTubeAdapter(DisplayListView.this,VideoURL,VideoTitle);
   lv.setAdapter(you);
   et_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

   et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           String text = et_search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
           you.filter(text);
       }
   });
   }
   ```
2. Adapter.java

   ```
   ArrayList<String> mVideo=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> mTitle=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> mThumb=new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> orig;
   // Filter Class
   public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    orig.clear();
   Log.i(TAGYTAdap,"charText:"+charText);
   if (charText.length() == 0) {
       orig.addAll(mTitle);
   } else {
       for (String wp : mTitle) {
           Log.i(TAGYTAdap,"wp:"+wp);
          if (wp.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                   .contains(charText)) {
               orig.add(wp);
           }
        }
     }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Comment: Instead of creating separate list, create one model class and than create list of that model class.Here is a perfect solution of your requirement.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search View and Edittext both can be use for this filter thing but Search view is better one.!

here you go now this will work fine.! hope so

I have done same thing here is my code.!

```
 // Filter Function
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (Words wp : arraylist)
            {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And called it in Main.!

```
 // Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```